# Data in list getting repeat on scroll

Tags: android, listview

Data of my list view is getting repeat on scroll though my clicks are working fine , i know this is the issue regarding to setTag or positioning but i am not able to fix it...so i need little help from you guys

here is my getView function of adapter :-

```html
@Override
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  final ViewHolder viewHolder;
  final int i = position;
  final WholeProductList listItem = mProductList.get(position);

  if (convertView == null) {
   convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(
     R.layout.list_comapare_product, parent, false);
   viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
   viewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
   viewHolder.tvProductName.setText(mProductList.get(position)
     .getName());
   viewHolder.imgProduct = (ImageView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.img_product);
   viewHolder.imgadd = (ImageView) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.img_plus);
   viewHolder.mRlConatiner = (RelativeLayout) convertView
     .findViewById(R.id.rl_container);
   convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

  } else {
   viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
  }
  viewHolder.mRlConatiner.setTag(position);
  viewHolder.mRlConatiner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (tickedItems.contains((Integer) v.getTag())) {
     // Already ticked, set to plus
     viewHolder.imgadd.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources()
       .getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));
     tickedItems.remove((Integer) v.getTag());
     if (((AppController) activity.getApplicationContext()).cartItemList
       .contains(listItem)) {
      ((AppController) activity.getApplicationContext()).cartItemList
        .remove(listItem);
     }
    } else {
     tickedItems.add((Integer) v.getTag());
     viewHolder.imgadd.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources()
       .getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
     if (!((AppController) activity.getApplicationContext()).cartItemList
       .contains(listItem)) {
      ((AppController) activity.getApplicationContext()).cartItemList
        .add(listItem);
     }
    }
    Session.getmCountImage().setvisibilityOn();
   }
  });
  if (tickedItems.contains(position))
   viewHolder.imgadd.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources()
     .getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));

  else
   viewHolder.imgadd.setImageDrawable(activity.getResources()
     .getDrawable(R.drawable.plus));

  return convertView;
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        final int i = position;
        final WholeProductList listItem = mProductList.get(position);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_comapare_product, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvProductName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_product_name);
            viewHolder.imgProduct = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_product);
            viewHolder.imgadd = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_plus);
            viewHolder.mRlConatiner = (RelativeLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.rl_container);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

/////////////This line should be here///////////////////////////////////
            viewHolder.tvProductName.setText(mProductList.get(position)
                    .getName());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        viewHolder.mRlConatiner.setTag(position);
        viewHolder.mRlConatiner.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saving the tag wrong. Set

```
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
```

after your init phase, i.e. the convert view handling, after the condition block.

Answer (score 0):

Please try is in this format:

```
if (convertView == null) {
//please setTag should be encountered in this block of code

        }
else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
//and here setText or any value
```